# addFirst method of ArrayDeque Class

Tags: java, arraydeque

The code of addFirst method in java.util.ArrayDeque class is

```
public void addFirst(E e) {
    if (e == null)
        throw new NullPointerException();
    elements[head = (head - 1) & (elements.length - 1)] = e;
    if (head == tail)
        doubleCapacity();
}
```

Here, I am not able to understand the meaning of

```
head = (head - 1) & (elements.length - 1)
```

Also, Suppose if array size is 10. head is at 0 and tail is at 9(Array is full). In this case, at what index system will do insertion? 
(My understanding is: if array is full then, first increase its size and then do insertion in the arraySize()-1 index.)

Comment: I had the same doubt :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The functionality of the following line is basically `(head - 1) MODULO (elements.length)`, so that subtracting 1 from head results in the maximum possible value instead of -1 when `head == 0`.

```
head = (head - 1) & (elements.length - 1)
```

10 is not  valid length of `elements`, according to the implementation, `elements.length` is always a power of two. If this were not the case the operation would not work.

Understanding why this works requires knowledge of bit operations.
Assuming `elements.length == 16 == 00010000b` and that the length of values are 8 bits instead of the actual 32 for simplicity's sake:

`(elements.length - 1)` is used to get a bit mask of ones n bits long, where 2^n is the current length of elements. `(elements.length - 1) == 15 == 00001111b` in this case.

If `head > 0` and `head < elements.length` (which is a given), then `(head - 1) & (elements.length - 1) == (head - 1)`, as ANDing with 1s does nothing.

If `head == 0`, `head - 1 == -1 == 11111111b`. (Two's complement signed integer notation, although you can also view it as a simple integer overflow.) ANDing with the mask `(head - 1) & 00001111b == 11111111b & 00001111b == 00001111b == 15`, which is the wanted value.

Answer (score 0):

Here its using `&` operator means it will perform Binary AND operation in both the integer.

lets assume your case head = 0 then head will become

head = -1

and elements.length = 16 (which is by default and also as @Adrian said it will be of only power of 2)

so performing the operation `-1 & 15` (i.e. 11111111 & 00001111) it will become 15 which is the target position to add the element.